# Detect if element is in view of Bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I'm loading a separate HTML page into a Bootstrap modal window. In that modal, there are elements that need to animate using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). I can probably get that part to work, but the problem I can't figure out is how to determine when an element that I want to animate is actually in view in the viewport when the modal is open so I can use jQuery to add the animate classes. Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but i think it shall work. First add a class to your elements so that they will be invisible by default:

```
.el {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then check when the modal gets opened and change their css with js to `visibility: visible;`

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.el').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

I suppose all attached animations will start running right after.